# Querying a DataTable using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ado.net, datatable

First apologies if I don't explain this properly, I've been at this for hours, and it's now morning.

I've tried so many methods, got so many errors that I can't remember the original version, nor can I solve the problem, here's my code, it's terrible as I should be using a join query my SP's are bugged on this server.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter ad;
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
ad = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM booking WHERE bookstartdate BETWEEN '" + ReturnDbDate(datefrom).ToString() + "' AND '" + ReturnDbDate(dateto).ToString() + "'", conn);
ad.Fill(ds, "CustomerIds");

ad = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT customerid, firstname, lastname, telephone, email FROM customer", conn);
ad.Fill(ds, "Customers");

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Customerid", typeof(String));
dt.Columns.Add("Firstname", typeof(String));
dt.Columns.Add("Lastname", typeof(String));
dt.Columns.Add("Telephone", typeof(String));
dt.Columns.Add("Email", typeof(String));

int lol = ds.Tables["CustomerIds"].Rows.Count;

foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables["CustomerIds"].Rows)
{
    IEnumerable<DataRow> r = from dr in ds.Tables["Customers"].AsEnumerable()
                             where dr.Field<Guid>("customerid").ToString() == row[2].ToString()
                             select dr;
    dt.Rows.Add(r);
}

return dt;
```

When I try loop through the dataset using the following:

```
foreach (DataRow rows in dt.Rows)
{
    sb.Append("<tr><td>" + rows["Customerid"].ToString() + "</td><td>" + rows[1] + "</td><td>" + rows[2] +"</td><td>" + rows[3] + "</td></tr>");
}
```

I get:

> System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection`1[System.Data.DataRow]

Anyone any ideas? Completely brain dead atm so it might be something simple.

Thanks

Edit:

```
DataRow r = from dr in ds.Tables["Customers"]
            where dr.Field<Guid>("customerid").ToString() == row[2].ToString()
            select dr;    
dt.ImportRow(r);
```

> Error: Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Data.DataTable'.  'Where' not found.

I'm assuming my LINQ syntax is not incorrect, although I think there's a `IEnumberable<T>.Where()` method? I remember it, just can't remember how to access it.

Edit2:

I fail, managed to re-create the problem again, sigh

```
 IEnumerable<DataRow> r = from dr in ds.Tables["Customers"].Select().Where(x => x.Field<Guid>("customerid").ToString() == row[2].ToString())
                            select dr;



                dt.ImportRow(r);
```

Comment: It's a case of comparing data from two dataset tables, and creating a new data table and populating it with the conditional data above

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`dt.Rows.Add()` takes in a `DataRow` but your providing `IEnumerable<DataRow>`
Also note that rows can only be added to a `DataTable` that has been created with `dt.NewRow()` try using `dt.ImportRow()` instead

**EDIT:**

Skip the temp DataTable and join the two datatables in the dataset instead.
Or even better, skip using linq and join the tables in the database query instead.

```
return 
  from dr in ds.Tables["Customers"].AsEnumerable()
  join dr2 in ds.Tables["CustomerIds"].AsEnumerable()
    on dr.Field<Guid>("customerid") equals dr2.Field<Guid>(2)
  select dr;
```

Plain SQL

```
public DataTable GetCustomers(DataTime datefrom, DataTime dateto)
{
    var sql = @"
        SELECT customer.customerid, firstname, lastname, telephone, email
        FROM customer
        JOIN booking
            ON customer.customerid = booking.customerid
        WHERE bookstartdate BETWEEN '" + ReturnDbDate(datefrom).ToString() + "' AND '" + ReturnDbDate(dateto).ToString() + "'";

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
    using (SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn))
    {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ad.Fill(ds);
            return ds.tables[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers, change my code a little, still got problems though sadly.

Comment: I love you so much right now lol, didn't realise inline join sql statements were possible. Problem solved

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget

```
using System.Linq;
```

otherwise you can't use neither LINQ extension method.

---

Try out this:

- Add reference to System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll
- `IEnumerable<DataRow> r = ds.Tables["Customers"].AsEnumerable();`
- Use any LINQ extension method against it:

  ```
  from r in ds.Tables["Customers"].AsEnumerable()
  where r.Field<Guid>("customerid") == row[2]
  select r;
  ```

---

Your ADO.NET code rather better could look like this:

```
using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
    using (SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter("", conn))
    {
        ad.Fill(ds);
    }

    // access ds;
}
```